# Cordova Audio Recorder API Plugin Unable find file

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using the "Cordova Audio Recorder API Plugin" in my app its working great,but i am unable find the recorded file,In plugin they say it is stored in

"iOS: /var/mobile/Applications//Library/NoCloud/.m4a"

"Android: /data/data//files/.m4a"

I am unable to get it,even i try to change the directory but still no luck below is code which i change the directory.Need help

```
window.plugins.audioRecorderAPI.record(function(savedFilePath) {
var fileName = savedFilePath.split('/')[savedFilePath.split('/').length - 1];
var directory;
if (cordova.file.documentsDirectory) {
directory = cordova.file.documentsDirectory; // for iOS 
} else {
directory = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory; // for Android 
}
$cordovaFile.copyFile(
cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileName,
directory, "new_file.m4a"
)
.then(function (success) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(success));
}, function (error) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
 }, function(msg) {
   alert('ko: ' + msg);
 }, 3);
```

Comment: Can you link to the plugin's repository?

Comment: "https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audio-recorder-api" this  link